# IN Clause is not taking dynamic passed value in SQL 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have below SQL Procedure where I am passing and setting dynamic values.

**Code: SQL Procedure Name: GetArchivedData**

```
      ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetArchivedData](@PublicationURL varchar(100),@Number int,@Action varchar(max))  

AS
DECLARE @TEST Varchar(max)
IF (@Action = 'ALL')
BEGIN
SET @TEST = '''ADD'''+','+'''UPD'''+','+'''DEL''';
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
SET @TEST = @Action
END
IF (@Number !=0)
BEGIN
PRINT 'Inside'+ @TEST 
     BEGIN TRANSACTION TRAN1 

           SELECT 
              1 AS Tag,  
              NULL AS Parent,  
              NULL AS [root!1!],  
              NULL AS [Item!2!Id],  
              NULL AS [Item!2!Action],  
              NULL AS [Item!2!Publication_Id],  
              NULL AS [Item!2!Item_Reference_Id],  
              NULL AS [Item!2!Item_type],  
              convert( datetime, '9999-01-01' ) AS [Item!2!Last_Published_Date],  
              NULL AS [Item!2!Url],  
              NULL AS [Item!2!Schema_Id]  

              UNION  

              SELECT TOP (@Number) 
              2,  
              1,  
              '1',  
              T.ID,  
              T.ACTION,  
              T.PUBLICATION_ID,  
              T.ITEM_REFERENCE_ID,  
              T.ITEM_TYPE,  
              T.LAST_PUBLISHED_DATE,  
              T.URL,  
              T.SCHEMA_ID    
              FROM DBO.AUTN_ITEMS T WHERE FLAG=1 AND ACTION IN (@TEST) AND URL LIKE @PublicationURL+'%' 
              ORDER BY [Item!2!Last_Published_Date] DESC
              FOR XML EXPLICIT                

     COMMIT TRANSACTION TRAN1   
END
ELSE IF (@Number = 0)
BEGIN
PRINT 'Outside'+ @TEST 
     BEGIN TRANSACTION TRAN2

           SELECT 
              1 AS Tag,  
              NULL AS Parent,  
              NULL AS [root!1!],  
              NULL AS [Item!2!Id],  
              NULL AS [Item!2!Action],  
              NULL AS [Item!2!Publication_Id],  
              NULL AS [Item!2!Item_Reference_Id],  
              NULL AS [Item!2!Item_type],  
              convert( datetime, '9999-01-01' ) AS [Item!2!Last_Published_Date],  
              NULL AS [Item!2!Url],  
              NULL AS [Item!2!Schema_Id]  

              UNION  

              SELECT  
              2,  
              1,  
              '1',  
              T.ID,  
              T.ACTION,  
              T.PUBLICATION_ID,  
              T.ITEM_REFERENCE_ID,  
              T.ITEM_TYPE,  
              T.LAST_PUBLISHED_DATE,  
              T.URL,  
              T.SCHEMA_ID    
              FROM DBO.AUTN_ITEMS T WHERE FLAG=1 AND  ACTION IN (@TEST) AND URL LIKE @PublicationURL+'%' 
              ORDER BY [Item!2!Last_Published_Date] DESC
              FOR XML EXPLICIT   

     COMMIT TRANSACTION TRAN2 
END
RETURN
```

**Excuting SQL Procedure:**

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[GetArchivedData]
        @PublicationURL = N'/in',
        @Number = 0,
        @Action = N'ALL'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

I can see the values are getting set properly, if I am printing it in the procedure however one value works perfectly but when I am setting `SET @TEST = '''ADD'''+','+'''UPD'''+','+'''DEL''';` no results are returned

Please suggest!!

Comment: Pass xml and use .nodes OR use dynamic OR use table function to convert list to recordset for IN values list.

Comment: @Revoua, I didn't understand your suggestion, please clarify more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Table Variable instead of @Test as string like this,

```
DECLARE  @ActionTbl table ([Action] varchar(3))
IF (@Action = 'ALL')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @ActionTbl SELECT 'Add' AS ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'UPD' AS ID
    UNION ALL   
    SELECT 'DEL' ID 
END
ELSE
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO @ActionTbl VALUES(@Action)
END
```

And in query use

```
ACTION IN (Select Action from @ActionTbl)
```

Instead of

```
ACTION IN (@TEST)
```

Comment: do we need to drop the table @ActionTbl after processing?

Comment: No, you don't need to drop  @ActionTbl, since it is a table Variable like any other variable.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the main issue here -  you CAN'T use `IN` to search one string in another. `IN` is used to search value in the row set of values. Also the @TEST STRING value is `'ADD,'UPD','DEL'` (each item is with quotas). I guess the `Action` field contains values without quotas so additional y to other answers there is one more way:

Replace

```
ACTION IN (@TEST)
```

with

```
  @TEST LIKE '%'''+ACTION+'''%'
```